# how can I import module if an installed one is incorrect?

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, sqlite, mysql-python

I'm getting below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TicketGeneration_test.py", line 6, in <module>
    from MysqlConnection import SQLConnection
  File "/Users/ashish.kumar/MerchantRisk/June5th/reports/MysqlConnection.py", line 1,     in <module>
    import MySQLdb
ImportError: No module named MySQLdb
```

I've already tried :

```
 pip install MySQL-python 
 pip install mysqlclient
```

My python version is Python `2.7.16`

Comment: Ensure you are using the same environment of python where you have installed

Comment: `pip install pymysql`
`import pymysql as MySQLdb`

Comment: try this https://edwards.sdsu.edu/research/installing-mysqldb-module-for-python-2-7-for-ubuntu-12-04/

Comment: @RaghavendraGupta.    import pymysql as MySQLdb
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymysql'.      I'm surely missing something..

Comment: did this run fine? `pip install pymysql`

Comment: yes, it says : Requirement already satisfied: pymysql